# Auto align does not work

Tags: html, css

I am writing a PHP page, but when I re size the browser the div element doesn't move. 
ie.

```
       <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    body{background-color: #CDD3FA}

                    #paragraph {
                        margin-right: 300px;
                        margin-left: 300px;
                        width: 720px;
                        border: 1px solid #a1a1a1; 
                        padding: 10px 40px; 
                        background: #E0E2EE; 
                        border-radius: 25px;
                        text-align: justify;

                    }
        </style>

            </head>
            <body>
              <div id="paragraph">
                        <p><strong> Note: Application for TAC approval is similar, but not identical, to Section II of the Institutional Ethics Committee Application Form. As far as possible, the total length of the TAC application, with the responses, should not exceed six pages or 2500 words. Use of simple language is preferred. Ensure that full forms or definitions of all abbreviations and acronyms are given. The investigator should ensure that sufficient information is provided to show that the study is scientifically sound and technically feasible, and that the expected outcome of the study is clearly defined. If the sub-sections A to H are not sufficient to provide these aspects of the research, additional details of the study should be provided in sub-section I.</strong></p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

How do I fix the centering when I am resizing the page?

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Update Code and Fiddle)

```
 #paragraph {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    width: 300px;
                    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1; 
                    padding: 10px 40px; 
                    background: #E0E2EE; 
                    border-radius: 25px;
                    text-align: justify;

                }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/E33pZ/1/)

Comment: * replace your margin-right and margin-left with this

Answer (score 0):

work with your css, try css:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this this should work and let me know if this is wrong  [click here][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/9sLdV/1/
```